# Javascript: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null(5)

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror

Where's the error, I am basically trying to get the grid display W or B, but it just keep displaying error, which is a typeError:cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null. I've been trying to debug it since yesterday night. I am very new to HTML.

```
<script>
    function play(id)
    {
        //var first = document.getElementById("current_turn").innerHTML;
        //document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = first;
        //if (first=="B")
        //{
        //  document.getElementById("current_turn").innerHTML="W";
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //  document.getElementById("current_turn").innerHTML="B";
        //}
        var currentTurn = document.getElementById("current_turn").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = currentTurn;
        if (document.getElementById(id) == "X")
        {
            document.getElementById("current_turn").innerHTML="O";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("current_turn").innerHTML="X";
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="font-family:Arial">Gomoku</h1>
    <h3 style="font-family:Arial">Introduction</h3>


        <div class="board">
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="0-0" onclick="play(0, 0);"></div>
                    <div id="1-0" onclick="play(1, 0);"></div>
                    <div id="2-0" onclick="play(2, 0);"></div>
                    <div id="3-0" onclick="play(3, 0);"></div>
                    <div id="4-0" onclick="play(4, 0);"></div>
                    <div id="5-0" onclick="play(5, 0);"></div>
                    <div id="6-0" onclick="play(6, 0);"></div>
                    <div id="7-0" onclick="play(7, 0);"></div>
                    <div id="8-0" onclick="play(8, 0);"></div>
                    <div id="9-0" onclick="play(9, 0);"></div>
                    <div id="10-0" onclick="play(10, 0);"></div>
                    <div id="11-0" onclick="play(11, 0);"></div>
                    <div id="12-0" onclick="play(12, 0);"></div>
                    <div id="13-0" onclick="play(13, 0);"></div>
                    <div id="14-0" onclick="play(14, 0);"></div>
                </div>

        </div>  
    <div class="text">

        Current Turn: <div id="current_turn">X</div><br />
        <br />

    </div>


</body>
```

Comment: you have written function play(id) with one parameter and calling it with two argument '<div id="0-10" onclick="play(0, 10);">'....how

Answer (score 1):

Your play function takes two arguments of which you only use the first one in the function body assuming that it conforms with the format of the element ids.

So you should change your function to

```
Function play ( x, y ){
    var id = x+"-"+y;
    //...
}
```

There are some more issues about your code wrt maintainability and best practices:

- use type-safe comparisons ( `===`, `!==` instead of `==`, `!=` )
- separate html definition from event handler assignment.
  The free [jquery JS lib](http://jquery.com) provides support to achieve this and helps
  With numerous other features, in particular cross-browser code normalisations.

Comment: That did work, but it can only print X but not O's. I wanted it to switch off every time I clicked it. Could you help me on that too? Thanks.

Comment: Change your condition to `if (document.getElementById(id).innerHTML == "X")`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change either `function play(id)` or `onclick` call as both arguments are not matching and hence it is throwing null for innerHTML property because not getting element with id specified at line

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = currentTurn;
```

change function as below :

```
function play(id1, id2)
{
  var id = id1+"-"+id2;
  // then write your if else part
}
```

or change onclick like below :

```
onclick="play('0-3');"
```

Answer (score -1):

You shoudn't put the script before the  `Current Turn: <div id="current_turn">X</div><br />`.

You will get nothing because you have the `current_turn` be defined.

Comment: This shouldn't matter since `play()` is called through an `onclick` handler. Once the page is fully loaded and one of the divs is clicked, the whole DOM should be available to the function.